# HoloViews Area Overlay Axes and Labels

Tags: python-3.x, overlay, holoviews

I'm trying to overlay `Scatter` and `Area`, but the latter is causing the axes and their labels to disappear.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

data = dict(A=["A1", "A1", "A1", "A1"], B=["B1", "B1", "B1", "B2"], C=[10, -5, 23, 9], D=[0, 5, -7, 6])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df_hv = hv.Dataset(df)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[("C", "@C{0,.0}"),
              ("D", "@D{0,.0}")]
)

scatter = df_hv.to(hv.Scatter, kdims=["C", "D"], vdims=["C", "D"], groupby=["A", "B"]).redim.label(x="A (unitA)", y="B (unitB)")
area =  hv.Area([(0, 0), (10, 9), (30, 8), (25, -11), (15, -12), (0, 0)]).opts(style=dict(color="lightgrey", line_color="white", line_dash=None, alpha=0.5)).redim.label(x="A (unitA)", y="B (unitB)")
```

And then:

```
%%opts Scatter [tools=[hover]] (size=10)
scatter * area
```

The result is as follows:

[image: With hv.Area]

If you replace the `hv.Area` line with the following,

```
area =  hv.Curve([(0, 0), (10, 90), (30, 80), (25, 110), (15, 120)]).opts(style=dict(line_color="black", line_dash="dashed", alpha=0.5))
```

you'll see the axes and their labels:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

```
bokeh=0.12.7
holoviews=1.8.3
pandas=0.20.2
python=3.6.1
```

**UPDATE**

After one of the comments, I changed the area as follows,

```
area =  hv.Area([(0, 0), (10, 9), (30, 8), (25, -11), (15, -12), (0, 0)]).opts(style=dict(color="lightgrey", line_color="white", line_dash="solid", alpha=0.5)).redim.label(x="A (unitA)", y="B (unitB)")
```

But that has an ugly line along the origin as a side-effect:

[image: With hv.Area 2]

And it doesn't get better if I do `line_color="lightgrey"`.

**UPDATE 2**

Adding the option `line_alpha=0` solved the issue as recommended in one of the comments.

```
area =  hv.Area([(0, 0), (10, 9), (30, 8), (25, -11), (15, -12), (0, 0)]).opts(style=dict(color="lightgrey", line_color="white", line_dash="solid", alpha=0.5, line_alpha=0)).redim.label(x="A (unitA)", y="B (unitB)")
```

[image: Solved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how or why this is occurring (I suspect it's something in BokehJS), but it seems to be the `line_dash=None` in style options for the `Area` element, if you remove it or replace it with `line_dash='solid'` the axes return.

I'll follow up and will probably file an issue in bokeh.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The problem with making line_dash="solid" is that I get an ugly line along the origin. I changed the example to show that.

Comment: Try setting `line_alpha=0` or `line_width=0` instead.

Comment: line_alpha=0 did the trick! line_width didn't solve the issue. I updated the post.